# Stream a file from using camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to Camel and was trying to work on streaming a log. 
I am trying to stream a log which keeps on changing. So , once my route starts it should keep on streaming the file and give every line to the processor.
I tried the following:
But then I suppose there might be a better of doing this and just send one line to the reader to process every time. 
Also, keep the route running to read every time log gets overwritten.

```
from("stream:file?fileName=/usr/dir/filename=logs.txt?options")
               .process(new Reader());
```

Also, How I would be able to read the line then in the processor. I searched for hours and I am not able to find a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/stream.html) for the Camel Stream component suggests the following:

```
from("stream:file?fileName=/usr/dir/logs.txt&scanStream=true&scanStreamDelay=1000")
    .process(new Reader());
```

Also, you're using the fileName option twice, maybe a typo?

If you want to do some custom processing on each line you can create your own Processor:

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        //Perform some logic and put it back in the exchange
        exchange.getIn().setBody(body);
    }
}
```

Then in your camel context:

```
Processor myProcessor = new MyProcessor();
...
from("file:///dir").process(myProcessor);
```

Comment: Thanks noMad17. Solved it yesterday. I opened up a buffer reader in the reader. Then did each line from log file in the reader process. 
Also, timed my route. So now it goes and checks to see if I have a new content in file and reads that.